# Does VIM definition of 'inner-word' change based upon context?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to figure out why the same key pattern `viw`
appears to behave differently in separate contexts

I have two buffers where the cursor is [ ]

In one a javascript file:

```
import {[f]oo, bang} from './utilities'
```

**visual selection: foo**

The other, :help

```
"inner word", select [count] words (see |word|).
White space between words is counted too.
When used in Visual linewise mode "iw" switches to
Visual characterwise [m]ode.
```

**visual selection: mode.**

I'm confused why in the first the inner-word excludes the punctuation character comma **,**
and the second includes the punctuation **.**

What accounts for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (well not technically, the definition does not change, because it is per definition variable). Vim is (if configured to be) filetype sensitive. see `:h filetype`.
So EVERY setting can be different in a different filetype.

The one you are looking for is `iskeyword`. This controlls which characters are word boundaries. `:h iskeyword` states:

```
For a help file it is set to all non-blank printable characters except '*', '"' and '|' (so that CTRL-] on a command finds the help for that command).
```

So `.` belongs to the word, like a-z

Comment: Thank you kindly.  I can't believe I've never read this in the many times I've tried to precisely grok text objects

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name `:h iw` points you to `:h word` which points you to `:h iskeyword`. Vim help is mighty once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I would answer "no". The definition itself doesn't change. It's just that the definition includes a variable part that can indeed change from one context to another.

Comment: @romainl ... well yes... that is technically the truth... damit